# Why JavaScript methods inside a function used as an object constructor need to be assigned to a property of the object?

Tags: javascript

I'm studying JavaScript and I saw this example from w3schools.com (yes, I know about w3fools):

```
<script>
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.age=age;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;

this.changeName=changeName; 
function changeName(name)
{
this.lastname=name;
}

}
myMother=new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");
myMother.changeName("Doe");
document.write(myMother.lastname);
</script>
```

When I tried to remove the `this.changeName=changeName;` part, the function no longer functioned. My question is why is that part needed? There was no explanation about it, it was just there.

Comment: That's one of the reasons w3schools isn't advised... If I'm not mistaken, by doing this, you're actually making the method public by assigning it to the instance (this)

Comment: @Bartdude I've been seeing a lot that w3schools is a bad resource but I've been trying to work with it because it's the only one that kind of has everything in it. Any alternatives you might suggest?

Comment: @kentz I might suggest [MDN's tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials); in particular  their [beginner JavaScript Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide). The lesson [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) covers much of what you ask here. **Disclaimer**: I never used MDN for beginning learning, so I don't know how helpful their tutorials are for new developers (although their reference material is very good).

Comment: Well, I must admit a lot of my research work  generally passes by stackoverflow at some point, going or not to more specific articles afterwards. There's no point having everything centralized (on W3Schools) if it's not up-to-date, not always reliable, sometimes bad practices, not much explained/detailed, etc, ... But I must admit I didn't learn JS online : at the time I did learn it, books were still the best existing resources on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We might rewrite the code to make it clearer:

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) {
    ...
    var myChangeNameFunc = function(name) {
        this.lastname = name;
    }
    this.changeName = myChangeNameFunc; 
}
```

Or even shorter, using an anonymous function:

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor) {
    ...
    this.changeName = function(name) {
        this.lastname = name;
    }
}
```

The `new` keyword creates a new object, allows you to modify that object through the `this` identifier, and then returns the new object. By doing `this.changeName=changeName`, you assign the `changeName` function to the `changeName` property of the newly-created object in `this`.

That's a little confusing, so in my first example above, I did `this.changeName = myChangeNameFunc` to make it clear that the constructor-scope variable `myChangeNameFunc` and the object property `this.changeName` are different variables (although in this case they ultimately refer to the same object).

Without that assignment, the `myChangeNameFunc` function is never attached to the newly-created object -- it's just a function defined within the `person` constructor function.

---

Some bonus background:

- `function(name) { this.lastname = name; }` is a *function expression*.
- `var myNameChangeFunc = function() { }` *assigns* that function expression to a local variable in the constructor. (Variables in JS are function-scoped, so `myNameChangeFunc` is not accessible outside of the constructor function.)
- function changeName() { } is a *function definition*. This is basically the same as `var changeName = function() { }`, except that the assignment is "hoisted" to the top of the containing function (so imagine it as the first line of the constructor function).

Thus, the function is originally stored in a constructor-local variable. By storing it in a property of `this`, it become a method of the constructed object, instead of just a function that is local to the constructor.

Comment: So `myChangeNameFunc` is some kind of variable that automatically points to the function of the same name?

And the changeName function in the example I presented was never actually linked to the person function in any way?

Also, does it mean that I have to do that `this.changeName=changeName;` part with every function that I'd like to call from an instance of another object?

Comment: If you want a method defined in the closure of an object to be called through an instance of this object, yes you'll definitely need to "assign" this function to an object property. If you don't do that you'll only be able to call the method from inside the object, making it kind of a "private method"

Answer (score 3):

Seen alone, the `function changeName` is local to the `person` constructor scope and therefore not visible outside that scope -- it's somewhat like a private method.

If you want to that method to be callable from the outside world then you have to create a property on the newly created person and set its value to that function. That way it can be accessed as `myMother.changeName` (just like any other property) and invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this example:

```
var object = {};

function someFn() {}
```

Here you can clearly see that `object` doesn't have a `someFn` member. If you want `object` to have the `someFn` function we need to do:

```
object.someFn = someFn;
```

Well in your example you can imagine that `this` is `object` in the previous example. `changeName` is just a private variable declared in the constructor's function scope so you need to assign it to `this` if you want it to be a public function on your instanciated object.